# Sending javascript code to a chrome app via the remote debug protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, chromium

In the context of a unit test I need to send some code to the console of a chrome app I am developing. It's [clear](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#type-Debuggee) that I can do that from the `chrome.debug` API, but is there a way to do that from outside the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way; if you can do something with `chrome.debug` you can do so with remote debugging.

You need to [enable remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote) with command line switches; you can then connect to Chrome with a debugger client instance.

Google lists some [existing debugger clients](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients), and you can implement your own by following the [debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index) (which works over HTTP+WebSockets).

The procedure for a debugger client is to request `/json` from the debugger port over HTTP, which lists all possible debug targets; the client then connects to the WebSocket associated with that target to work with it.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? I looked into the protocol a bit but couldn't find a way to set the debuggee to an extension, or even a reference to a debuggee at all. Looking a bit into the code it looks like when the debuggee is another extension the event is dispatched internally and not through the protocol, but I could be wrong about this.

Comment: Read the first link; you need to access the `/json` URL for a list of debuggees and then connect to the appropriate WebSocket port. At least that's how I read it; I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: What do I do after connecting via WebSocket?